# Git reflog and doing a fresh clone?

Tags: git

If you want to track changes that have happened in your git repository you can use https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog e.g. to restore a branch if it was deleted locally/remotely by accident?

But as I understand git reflog only makes sense in the context of a local repository. Meaning each time you do a completely fresh clone the git reflog will be empty for all branches. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is correct. If you clone a project the reflog is empty and the first entry is for example:

```
fd7cb08 HEAD@{0}: clone: from https://github.com/xxxx
```

> Reference logs, or "reflogs", record when the tips of branches and other references were updated in the local repository.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that first entry: make sure to use Git 2.28+.

Before Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), the reflog entries for "`git clone`" and "`git fetch`" did not anonymize the URL they operated on.

See [commit 46da295](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46da295a77066994a663a47dc044f6c6fe582d26) (04 Jun 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 524caf8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/524caf80358b1158c40d1947e61d576c8a0c0a8c), 18 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`clone/fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46da295a77066994a663a47dc044f6c6fe582d26): anonymize URLs in the reflog
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> Even if we strongly discourage putting credentials into the URLs passed via the command-line, there *is* support for that, and users *do* do that.
>
> Let's scrub them before writing them to the reflog.

So if you clone with `git clone  https://me:MyGitHubPassword@github.com/xxxx`, the first entry will be:

```
46da295 HEAD@{0}: clone: from https://github.com/xxxx
```